# hive-site.xml is being ignored by hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

My hive-site.xml contains metastore details for mysql, and I am trying to pass it to hive via oozie but for some reason it is ignoring it. It is still trying to connect metastore using derby.
I am trying to find out how to specify my hive-site.xml.

If I use command line client then mysql database is used as a metastore and I can see the tables created by hive in mysql under TBLS.

If I run it as a workflow through oozie it is trying to connect to derby metastore.

```
Here are two lines from log.
6649 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence  - DataNucleus Persistence Factory - Vendor: "DataNucleus"  Version: "2.0.3"
6649 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence  - DataNucleus Persistence Factory initialised for datastore URL="jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true" driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" userName="APP"
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks
Ravi

Hadoop 1.2.1
Hive 0.11
OOzie 3.3.2

Comment: Have you uploaded the file on HDFS? Are you sure the path you have provided in the Oozie Hive action  is proper?

Comment: Are you using `oozie.hive.defaults` ?

Comment: Yes. The oozie hive action is being invoked all right. But after getting invoked it is accessing derby metastore instead of mysql metastore.

Yes I am. It is pointing to hive-site.xml on HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting the below configurations in your workflow xml. You can set it as global so that it will be applicable for all hive nodes.

```
<global>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
            <value>${hivemetastorelocal}</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
            <value>${hivemetastoreuris}</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout</name>
            <value>${hivemetastoreclientsockettimeout}</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
            <value>${hivemetastorewarehousedir}</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>hive.metastore.execute.setugi</name>
            <value>${hivemetastoreexecutesetugi}</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
</global>
```